# What is difference between R5 vs T3 servers in AWS in terms of network bandwidth

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

We are using below EC2 instance in AWS environment for our project

- t3.2xlarge

Now as we are using application where support team is suggesting to use R5 servers to solve issue related to network connectivity issues.

I can see features in below link but not sure which one will resolve network issue.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

This feature ?
With R5d instances, local NVMe-based SSDs are physically connected to the host server and provide block-level storage that is coupled to the lifetime of the R5 instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the recommendation to switch from T3 to R5 for network connectivity reasons is because a T3 instance has "up to 5Gbps" network performance, while an R5 server will have "up to 10Gbps" or more depending on the specific size you pick.

These values are listed under the column labeled "Networking Performance (Gbps)" on the page you linked.

Comment: So you mean if within a second, it consume 5Gbps and will start latency in connectivity between servers 
If yes, that means, we need to check if 10Gbps is good enough or should go for more based on business requirements, right ?

Comment: Will "Cluster Placement Group" can solve this issue ? I mean without scale up

Comment: From my understanding an R5 also has better memory handling doesnt it?

Comment: @blamb I believe the R* series of instance types generally have more memory (RAM) than the corresponding T* instance types. I'm not aware of any better "handling" of the memory.